# How to consolidate duplicate categories in the same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to calculate the total number of companies associated with each active investor.

'df' represents my original dataframe, in which the 'active_investors' column displays a list of active investors for each company listed. For example, one row might contain Company A, listing investors 1,2,3,4.

What I am trying to do is split the dataframe such that it displays company A as four separate rows i.e. for each investor 1, 2, 3 and 4.

So far, I have the following code:

```
#Separate names of investors for each company
df1 = df %>% separate_rows(active_investors, sep = ",")

#Total number of companies each investor has invested in 
investor = aggregate(data.frame(count = df1$company_name), list(active_investors = df1$active_investors), length)
```

The problem is that some investors are listed twice i.e. the same investor name, but are listed as two separate investors. I am unsure how to compile the frequencies (i.e. total companies the investor has invested in) such that these duplicates are removed.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Hi Anu! Would you mind please adding a reproducible excerpt of your dataframe `df` so we can run your code from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df <- data.frame(company_name=c(1:3),b=c("1,2,3","2,3,4","4,5"))) 
test_investors <- df %>% 
                  mutate(b1 = str_split(string=b,pattern=",")) %>% 
                  select(b1) %>% 
                  pull(.) 
 max_investors <- lapply(test_investors,function(x)length(x)) %>% 
                   unlist(.) %>% 
                  max(.)
 unique_investors <- df %>% 
                      separate(b,sep=",",
                              into=paste0("investor_",c(1:max_investors))) %>% 
                     select(company_name,starts_with("investor_")) %>% 
                     gather(-company_name,key="variable",value="investor") %>% 
                     filter(!is.na(investor)) %>% 
                     select(-variable)
```